# How do i have to set my working dictionary so other people can run my code from USB

Tags: r, working-directory

On Monday i have to send in my Master-Thesis. 
The codes are now on an USB-Stick. 
Are there any things i have to be careful about, so my supervisor can replicate my codes easily?
Are there differences between the working directory i choose (on the stick and his PC)?

2nd question would be: How do i find all packages i used. 
I already made a script with all packages i used, however, how can i be sure i haven't forgotten any package.

Do all files (codes and data) have to be in the same folder or can i set a folder as working directory and split that in other folders so its structured?

Thank you very much for every answer !!

Comment: This is a very broad topic. Maybe check out [this reproducibiity guide](https://ropensci.github.io/reproducibility-guide/sections/introduction/) or things like the [here package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=here) to being safer about file locations

Comment: share through github?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what kind of application you're building, but you can easily test your application on a USB drive before providing it to your professor.

1. Properly package your project onto the USD drive.
2. Verify that you can run it properly from your machine.
3. Verify that you can run it properly from someone else's machine.

If steps 2 or 3 fail, you must retry step 1 because something was obviously done incorrectly.